# Vue.js - Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot create property 'status' on number '2'

Tags: vue.js, controller

I have a `Vue` component in which I defined a method to retrieve data from `form` table in my db to display the answers into a table. The component method is this

```js
... rest of component
data() {
   return{
      totAnswersWithValueAInQuestion1: 0
   };
},
created() {
   this.totAnswersAInQ1();
},
methods: {
   async totAnswersAInQ1() {
      const activityName = this.$route.query.activityName;
      this.totAnswersWithValueAInQuestion1 = await jsonRequest('GET", '/stats?activity=${activityName}')
      return this.activityName;
   }
}
```

I omitted the template part of the component in which I call `{{ totAnswersWithValueAInQuestion1 }}`

I see `0`, as value of totAnswersWithValueAInQuestion1 and not the value I would like to display. In fact my console reports this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot create property 'status' on number '2'
    at _callee$ (requests.js:81:1)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js:63:1)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js:294:1)
    at Generator.next (runtime.js:119:1)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js:3:1)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js:25:1)
```

The controller method is this:

```java
@Transactional
@GetMapping(value = "/stats")
int totalAnswer1A_withValue1(@RequestParam String activityName) {
   return formRepository.countAnswersToQuestion1_AByValue(activityName);
}
```

and the repository method is this:

```java
@Repository
public interface FormRepository extends JpaRepository<Form, Integer> {

    @Query("select count(*) from Form where s.activityName = :activityName" )
    int countAnswersToQuestion1_AByValue(String activityName);
}
```

For now the repository method is a placeholder, I just wanted to see if the request worked. But it doesn't, since in my `form` table I have 2 entry in total. So it should display 2 as result of the query.

I can't figure out what the `status` property refers to.

The template part of my component is this

```
<template>
    <default-layout>
        <h1>Statistics</h1>
        <h3>Question 1 </h3>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>CRITERIA</th>
                    <th>A</th>
                    <th>B</th>
                    <th>C</th>
                    <th>D</th>
                    <th>E</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Criterium 1</td>
                    <td> {{ this.totAnswersWithValue1To1A }} </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
     </default-layout>
</template>
```

in which for now I just filled the first column, representing the count of answers with value A (that for now are just the total number of rows in the `form` table)

Comment: Please, confirm if the request has been sent correctly, and if the response is fine from your network panel.

Comment: @Mina yes, the request is fine from my network panel. And the response is 2 as the total number of entries in my db

Comment: @Mina so all fine from my side apparently.

Comment: The error said `Cannot create property 'status' on number '2'`, and that mean you use this code in your HTML `totAnswersWithValueAInQuestion1.status`

Comment: If not, please provide a working example of your code, in stackoverflow code snippet or any live editor like codesandbox.

Comment: @Mina, please take a look at the edited question including the template part

Comment: It should work fine by the code you are showing, could you reproduce the issue with a live editor like codesandbox. https://codesandbox.io/s/vue